# VisualForce having an issue with apex:actionFunction

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I have a visual force page. I have two values on this page that I need to pass to its controller. I am able to put these values in hidden fields on the page. I am now trying to use an apex:actionFunction to send them over to the controller.

Here is my relevant section of the VF Page.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="passStringToController" immediate="true" action="{!saveCaseRecord}" rerender="">
                        <apex:param name="p1" value="{!Case.Type}" assignTo="{!CaseType}" />
                        <apex:param name="p2" value="{!Case.Case_Type_Details__c}" assignTo="{!CaseSubType}" />
                    </apex:actionFunction>
```

Here is the relevant section of the apex controller code.
Edited:
The CaseType and CaseSubType variables have been declared as public in the controller.

```
public string CaseType {get;set;}
public string CaseSubType {get;set;}

    public PageReference saveCaseRecord()
    {

                System.Debug('BeforE calling createCase');
                System.Debug('CaseType ' + CaseType);
               System.Debug('CaseSubType ' + CaseSubType);
    }
```

I am definitely missing a piece here, because I am getting a null each time in the controller. I wrote a javascript function, but I don't believe it is firing. I am never seeing this value in the console log.

```
function passStringToController()
      {
                console.log('Function to get controller - passStringToController');
       };
```

I am calling the javascript passStringToController() from another javascript method on the same page.

Comment: Can you show the caseType and caseSubType declaration? you do not need js / actionfuncton to pass the value controller

Comment: how you are calling this actionFunction?

Comment: Don't create a JS function wit the same name as the actionFunction

Comment: What is the URL you are using to load the page and are you using a standardcontroller?  Better yet post all your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you call your passStringToController method you need to set the parameters there.

```
function passStringToController1()
      {
                passStringToController('Param 1', 'Param 2');
                console.log('Function to get controller - passStringToController');
       };
```

Then, in your action function

```
<apex:actionFunction name="passStringToController" immediate="true" action="{!saveCaseRecord}" rerender="">
      <apex:param name="p1" value="" assignTo="{!CaseType}" />
      <apex:param name="p2" value="" assignTo="{!CaseSubType}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

I am not entirely sure why setting the value directly would not work, as it should, but when I do it, that's usually the format I use.

Comment: You do not need to pass them if the param has the value set

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your actionfunction approach, but the way to get the param value in controller is 
As a poc try this 
Page:

           

Controller:

```
public string CaseType{get;set;}
public PageReference saveCaseRecord()
    {
    System.Debug('CaseType ' + CaseType);
}
```

Comment: if you use `assignTo` then `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get()` not needed, it will map to `setter` property

Comment: corrected @SantanuBoral I was copy pasting from another example and messed up

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of your code works for me at my DE.

I think main issue at your question is calling of the function.

Visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="ActionFunctionController">
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      passStringToController();
    };
</script>

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="passStringToController" immediate="true" action="{!saveCaseRecord}" rerender="values">
        <apex:param name="p1" value="{!Case.Type}" assignTo="{!CaseType}" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:outputText value="{!CaseType}" label="You have selected:" id="values" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class ActionFunctionController
{
    public string CaseType {get;set;}
    public string CaseSubType {get;set;}

    public ActionFunctionController(ApexPages.StandardController con)
    {

    }

    public PageReference saveCaseRecord()
    {
        System.Debug('BeforE calling createCase');
        System.Debug('CaseType ' + CaseType);
        return null;
    }
}
```